# Perl : how to print all the lines where second field is 0 and third field is 1

Tags: perl

How to print all the lines where second field is 0 and third field is 1 in Perl. I am specifically looking for a Perl Solution since there are few limitations in AIX Server (shell version is very old) and hence shell script is not working properly. Below is the sample file:

```
237576 6 1 RMAN_Backup Default_Backup clmjk 1442149024 0000000055 1442149079 23328
237575 0 3 RMAN_Backup Default_Backup clmjk 1442148956 0000000053 1442149009 2848
237574 0 1 RMAN_Backup Default_Backup clmjk 1442148954 0000000045 1442148999 544
237573 0 1 RMAN_Backup Default_Backup clmjk 1442145436 0000000053 1442145489 23328
237572 0 3 RMAN_Backup Default_Backup clmjk 1442145352 0000000047 1442145399 544
```

Comment: are you sure about shell?
$awk '$2 == "0" && $3 == "1" { print $0 }' 333.txt

Comment: Yes. The above command worked on shell but I have to perform some other tasks as well like I used while loop which didnt worked on AIX

Answer (score 4):

As a one-liner:

```
perl -ane 'print if 0 == $F[1] && 1 == $F[2]' input-file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits the input on whitespace to the `@F` array

Answer (score 1):

Read file line by line and split it with whitespace, then check if second field is 0 and third field is 1, write it in an output file.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die $!;
open my $fhout, ">", "outfile.txt" or die $!;

while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my @data = split (' ', $line);
    if ($data[1] == 0 && $data[2] == 1)
    {
        print $fhout $line, "\n";
    }
}
close $fh;
close $fhout;
```

Output (in output file 'outfile.txt'):

```
237574 0 1 RMAN_Backup Default_Backup clmjk 1442148954 0000000045 1442148999 544
237573 0 1 RMAN_Backup Default_Backup clmjk 1442145436 0000000053 1442145489 23328
```

Comment: How can we write the Output to a file ?

Comment: @RahulM: See the edit. I have edited code for writing in output file. Open a file in write and write those lines into file.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is perfect to be written as a Unix filter (reading from STDIN and writing to STDOUT).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {
  my @data = split;
  print if $data[1] == 0 && $data[2] == 1;
}
```

Run it like this:

```
$ ./filter < input_file > output_file
```

In fact, it's simple enough to write it as a command line program

```
$ perl -ane 'print if $F[1] == 0 && $F[2] == 1' input_file > output_file
```

Comment: Oops. Yes, that's what I meant. I'll fix it. Thanks.